# Aggregate Function Usage in SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've come across the following scenario in work.
Consider the following block:

```
Begin
Select Max(Column) from Table where some condition;
Exception
When No_Data_Found then
log into an audit table
End;
```

when there are actually no rows found, the control of execution is not getting diverted into the exception block but is returning NULL. 
When tried executing without the `MAX` function, the control of execution is caught in the exception block.

Can anyone please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAX is an aggregate function.  Aggregate functions perform a calculation on a set of values and return a single value.  They always return a single value per group (if you don't have a GROUP BY clause, you have one group).

Therefore, in your code, you'll never have NO_DATA_FOUND because MAX will always return one value - could be null.  If you take out MAX, it is a regular select, which may result in no rows selected, thereby going into the NO_DATA_FOUND block.

Comment: Thanks mate. That really helps. But could you please explain what you've mentioned about grouping in paranthesis?

Answer (score 0):

Pure aggregate functions--without corresponding grouped-by columns--always return exactly one row.

```
SQL> desc emp
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------
 EMPNO                                                 NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                                          VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                            VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                            NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                                       DATE
 SAL                                                            NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                                           NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                                         NUMBER(2)

SQL> SET NULL [NULL]
SQL> SELECT MAX(sal) FROM emp WHERE 1 = 0;

  MAX(SAL)
----------
[NULL]

SQL>
```